'EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs> does not contain a definition for 'FromDelegate''
Good day,
I trust you well, please assist on the below, I have a secured mailer project built in blazer, and I am implementing logic to accommodate different file types by adding an additional encryption library,  but problem seems to be related to the EventCallback.FromDelegate(OnChanged) syntax which I have been trying to fix with no success, please see below
                <Field Horizontal Padding="Padding.Is1">
                    <FieldLabel ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is2">Document:</FieldLabel>
                    <FieldBody ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is10">
                        <Field>
                            <FileEdit @ref="fileEdit" Placeholder="Upload pdf or xlsx files that are not more than 5MB each..." AutoReset="false" Multiple Changed="EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs>.FromDelegate(OnChanged)" Filter=".pdf, .xlsx" MaxFileSize="5000000" />
                            @if (EmailMessageDetails?.Attachments?.Any() == true)
                            {
                                <ListGroup class="list-group-item">
                                    @foreach (var attachment in EmailMessageDetails.Attachments)
                                    {
                                        <ListGroupItem class="list-group-item">
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check icon-color"></i> @attachment.FileName attached...
                                        </ListGroupItem>
                                    }
                                </ListGroup>
                            }
                        </Field>
                    </FieldBody>
                </Field>

I also tried to correcting the correspondence of the partial class like below, just gives me more errors please help,
private async Task OnChanged(FileChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var file in e.Files)
            {
                using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                EmailMessageDetails.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
                {
                    FileName = file.Name,
                    FileContent = memoryStream.ToArray()
                });
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        private async Task OnSave(SecureMailViewModel viewModel, bool save)
        {
            _isSending = true;
            if (_secureMailValidationsRef != null && _secureMailValidationsRef.ValidateAll())
            {
                await SecureMailHepler.SaveOrSendEmail(viewModel, EmailMessageDetails, save);
            }
            _isSending = false;
        }

        private async Task OnSaveAndSend(SecureMailViewModel viewModel)
        {
            await OnSave(viewModel, false);
        }

        private void BackToList()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/securemail-list");
        }
    }
}


Thank you
I updated the partial class, to resolve the event call back from:
       public async Task OnChanged(FileChangedEventArgs e, SpreadsheetDocumentType spreadsheetDocumentType)
       {

           try
           {

               foreach (var file in e.Files.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
               {

                   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                   {
                       await file.value.OpenReadStream(long.MaxValue).CopyToAsync(ms);

                       if (file.value.Type.Contains("pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                       {
                           await EncryptPdf(ms, file.value);
                           var fileStream = new FileStream($"{_folderToWriteTo}Protected_doc_{file.value.Name}", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                           streams.Add(fileStream);

                       }
                       else if (file.value.Type.Contains("xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                       {
                           using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
                           {
                               await EncryptPdf(ms, file.value);
                               var fileStream = new FileStream($"{_folderToWriteTo}Protected_doc_{file.value.Name}", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                               streams.Add(fileStream);
                           }
                       }
                       {
                           _toastService?.ShowWarning("Only PDF and XLSX files are supported.");

                           await fileEdit.Reset().AsTask();
                           return;
                           //var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                           //ms.Position = 0;    
                           //await ms.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                           //streams.Add(memStream);
                       }

                       var formFie = new FormFile(streams[file.i], 0, streams[file.i].Length, file.value.Type, file.value.Name)
                       {
                           Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                           ContentType = file.value.Type
                       };
                       EmailMessageDetails.Attachments.Add(formFie);

                   }

               }

           }
           catch (Exception exc)
           {
               _toastService?.ShowError($"An error occured while processing your request");
           }

To:
 private async Task OnChanged(FileChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var file in e.Files)
            {
                using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                EmailMessageDetails.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
                {
                    FileName = file.Name,
                    FileContent = memoryStream.ToArray()
                });
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        private async Task OnSave(SecureMailViewModel viewModel, bool save)
        {
            _isSending = true;
            if (_secureMailValidationsRef != null && _secureMailValidationsRef.ValidateAll())
            {
                await SecureMailHepler.SaveOrSendEmail(viewModel, EmailMessageDetails, save);
            }
            _isSending = false;
        }

        private async Task OnSaveAndSend(SecureMailViewModel viewModel)
        {
            await OnSave(viewModel, false);
        }

        private void BackToList()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/securemail-list");
        }
    }
}


Changed="EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs>.FromDelegate(OnChanged) is not how you call the event listener. Please refer to the Microsoft documentation.

Why so complicatred? First try: <FileEdit ... Changed="OnChanged" ... />

Your OnChanged method isn't a delegate, it's just a method.
